# How app.use match request which beggining with the same path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

If `app.use()` respond to any path that starts with `/` then why request `localhost:3000/foo` will match second method not first?

```
app.use("/",express.static('public'),
            function(req,res,next) { console.log("1"); next(); })

app.use("/", function(req, res) {
              res.send("2")
              var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
              console.log(fullUrl);
    })
```

Request: `localhost:3000/foo`

Output in console ( in web browser is printed only `2` not `index.html` from static folder):

```
1
http://localhost:3000/foo
1
http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route handlers and middleware are called, in order, until one of them doesn't chain to the next.

In your example, you have three handlers/middleware set up:

- `express.static`
- Your function that logs `"1"`
- Your function that sends `"2"` and logs the path

By default, Express's static serving looks for a matching file and sends it. If it doesn't find a matching file, it chains to the next handler/middleware via `next`. So it would appear that there is no `foo` or `favicon.ico` file in your `public` directory, because the static handler is chaining to your handler that logs `"1"`.

Your handler that logs `"1"` always chains to the next via `next()`. If it didn't, and it didn't send anything, the request would just hang there unresolved.

Your handler that returns `"2"` and logs the path doesn't chain, it uses [`res.send()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send), which ends the response.

More:

- https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html
- https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html
- https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html which links to https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html which is what says that it will chain if it doesn't find a match (instead of returning a 404).